# Streamsets Service does not start any more

Tags: streamsets

I just upgraded my MapR Cluster and I am trying to start Streamsets. However I get the following Error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: Expected exactly 1 stage lib jar but found 0 with name streamsets-datacollector-mapr_6_0-mep4-lib Jun 12 09:48:56 BGDTEST5 streamsets[24543]: at com.streamsets.pipeline.SDCClassLoader.bringStageAndProtoLibsToFront(SDCClassLoader.java:186) Jun 12 09:48:56 BGDTEST5 streamsets[24543]: at com.streamsets.pipeline.SDCClassLoader.getOrderedURLsForClassLoader(SDCClassLoader.java:404) Jun 12 09:48:56 BGDTEST5 streamsets[24543]: at com.streamsets.pipeline.SDCClassLoader.(SDCClassLoader.java:119) Jun 12 09:48:56 BGDTEST5 streamsets[24543]: at com.streamsets.pipeline.SDCClassLoader.getStageClassLoader(SDCClassLoader.java:389) Jun 12 09:48:56 BGDTEST5 streamsets[24543]: at com.streamsets.pipeline.SDCClassLoader.getStageClassLoader(SDCClassLoader.java:383) Jun 12 09:48:56 BGDTEST5 streamsets[24543]: at com.streamsets.pipeline.BootstrapMain.main(BootstrapMain.java:291) Jun 12 09:48:56 BGDTEST5 systemd[1]: sdc.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE Jun 12 09:48:56 BGDTEST5 systemd[1]: Unit sdc.service entered failed state. Jun 12 09:48:56 BGDTEST5 systemd[1]: sdc.service failed.

I can see the stage-lib in question in the streamsets-libs directory. This used to work seamlessly before. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: There's an answer to this at https://ask.streamsets.com/question/2254/error-starting-streamsets-on-a-mapr-cluster/?answer=2257#post-id-2257 - did you see that? Did you try that suggestion?